# Check folders & inside files are exists via shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

**Check folders & inside files are exists via shell script**

Here is a script I used to check folders and if it contains files inside it or not. But it's not taking the file names. Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 folder1="/root/scripts/1/"
 folder2="/root/scripts/2/"
 folder3="/root/scripts/3/"
 file1=start.sh
 file2=stop.sh

 CHKFOLDERS="folder1,folder2,folder3"
 CHKFILES="file1,file2"

# Check all passed path & programs are exist or not with needed permission like execute.

for fol in $(echo $CHKFOLDERS | sed "s/,/ /g"); do
 if [ ! -d "$fol" ]; then
  echo -e " $fol folder are not correct please check."
  exit 1
 fi

 for infile in $(echo $CHKFILES | sed "s/,/ /g"); do
  if [ ! -x "$((fol))/${fol}_${infile}" ]; then
    echo -e " \"${fol}_${infile}\" script is not correct or not executable please ckeck this."
        exit 2
        fi
      done
done
```

In this example, naming conventions are like this:

folder names: folder1, folder2, folder3

file names: folder1_file1, folder2_file2.

Answer (score 0):

the first problem is

```
CHKFOLDERS="folder1,folder2,folder3"
```

change it with

```
CHKFOLDERS="$folder1,$folder2,$folder3"
```

the second one is the if:

```
if [ ! -x "$((fol))/${fol}_${infile}" ]; then
```

change it with:

```
if [ ! -x "${fol}/${infile}" ]; then
```

also change the echo

```
echo -e " \"${fol}_${infile}\" script is not correct or not executable please ckeck this."
```

with
    echo -e " \"${fol}/${infile}\" script is not correct or not executable please ckeck this."

also it's better to change the folder declaration from

```
folder1="/root/scripts/1/"
```

to

```
folder1="/root/scripts/1"
```

this is the script after my changes:

```
#!/bin/bash

 folder1="/tmp/scripts/1"
 folder2="/tmp/scripts/2"
 folder3="/tmp/scripts/3"




file1=start.sh
 file2=stop.sh

 CHKFOLDERS="$folder1,$folder2,$folder3"
 CHKFILES="file1,file2"

# Check all passed path & programs are exist or not with needed permission like execute.

for fol in $(echo $CHKFOLDERS | sed "s/,/ /g"); do
 echo "folder[$fol]"
 if [ ! -d "$fol" ]; then
  echo -e " $fol folder are not correct please check."
  exit 1
 fi

 for infile in $(echo $CHKFILES | sed "s/,/ /g"); do
   echo "infile[$infile]"
  if [ ! -x "${fol}/${infile}" ]; then
    echo -e " \"${fol}/${infile}\" script is not correct or not executable please ckeck this."
        exit 2
        fi
      done
done
```

output:

```
sh-4.3$scriptTest.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
folder[/tmp/scripts/1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
infile[file1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
"/tmp/scripts/1/file1" script is not correct or not executable please ckeck   this.
```

Comment: Thanks Claudio, In your example file name get as "file1", but i need to get the file as : start.sh & stop.sh.
We can get it with use $file1,$file2 instead

Comment: yes sure you can replace CHKFILES="file1,file2" with CHKFILES="$file1,$file2"